# Extract specific data from a file with awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file as shown below. I would like to extract the .pdb IDs and its corresponding chains. How is this possible with `awk`?

```
>4HSU:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
PLGSRKCEKAGCTATCPVCFASASERCAKNGY
PKAFMADQQL
>4HSU:B|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
PLGSPEFSERGSKSPLKRAQETE
>4HSU:C|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
ARTMQTARKSTGGKAPRKQLATKAARKSAP
>4HT3:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
MERYENLFAQLNDRREGAF
>4HT3:B|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
MTTLLNPYFGEFGGMYVPQ
>4I0W:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
MENKAKVGIDFINTIPKQILTSLIEQYSPNNGEIELVVLYGDNFLRFKNSVDVIGAKVEDLGYGFGILII
>4I0W:B|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
AYDSNRASCIPSVWNNYNLTGEGILVGFLDT
>4I0W:D|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE
AYDSNRASCIPSVWNNYNLTGEGILVGFLLPLGDTITSGGWRIIVRKLNNYEGYFDIWLPIAEGLN
ERTRFLQPSVYNTLGIPATVEGVIS
 `
```

Desired output:

```
4HSU  A  B C
4HT3  A  B
4I0W  A  B D
```

Comment: have you tried something in particular ??

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kent$ awk -F'[>:|]' '/^>/{a[$2]=a[$2] OFS $3}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' file  
4I0W  A B D
4HSU  A B C
4HT3  A B
```

I am satisfied with my `FS` value: **`>:|`** like a cute face!

Answer (score 1):

Looks as though you want the output of everything in the original order; so, it takes some indirection to take care of this.  All the below works in POSIX AWK as requested (or at least gawk with LINT = 1) and has the addtional feature of keeping track of what is seen to eliminate duplicates.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
        FS="[>:|]"
        split("", t)     # table of output
        split("", r)     # row number in table for a ID
        split("", seen)  # keeps track of duplicates
        row=0
}

/^>/ && !($2 SUBSEP $3 in seen) {
        if ($2 in r) {
                i=r[$2]
                t[i] = t[i] OFS $3
        } else {
                r[$2] = row
                t[row++] = $2 OFS $3
        }
        seen[$2, $3] = 1
}

END {
        for (i=0; i<row; i++)
                print t[i]
}
```